# Computed style as a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, javascript-objects

Using [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) one can get the computed propertyValue for any property using `getPropertyValue(propertyKey)`.

Wondering if there is any method that can return a JavaScript object with all the computed `propertyKey: propertyValue`

```
{
  ...
  propertyKey: propertyValue,
  ...
}
```

Something similar to Chrome Dev Tool

[image]

If not probably I need to write it myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm not aware of a pre-rolled function which will do the work for us, it's fairly trivial to grab all of the properties as you've indicated you'd like to.

Here's some code that will achieve it. First, we define a function that will give us forEach functionality on non-array objects. Next, we get the computedStyle of the target element before finally iterating through the collection of returned  CSSStyleDeclaration objects, adding the property name and value to an object we later return.

```js
"use strict";

// useful for NodeList & HtmlCollection types
function forEach(array, callback, scope){for (var i=0,n=array.length; i<n; i++)callback.call(scope, array[i], i, array);} // passes back stuff we need

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);
function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
  var computedStyle = getTheStyle( document.getElementById('elem-container') );
  alert("Element has a height of: " + computedStyle.height + "\n" + "And a position of: " + computedStyle.position);
}

function getTheStyle(tgtElement)
{
 var result = {}, properties = window.getComputedStyle(tgtElement, null);
 forEach(
   properties, 
   function(prop)
   {
    result[prop] = properties.getPropertyValue(prop);
   }
  );
 console.log(result);
 return result;
}
```

```css
 #elem-container{
   position: absolute;
   left:     100px;
   top:      200px;
   height:   100px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="elem-container">dummy</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if such API existed, did not want to reinvent the wheel. Thanks for not only confirming but also providing the working solution.

Comment: Nobody ever wants to buy them, but I find great utility in at least knowing *how* to create a wheel.

Comment: I know _how_ create, and was not looking for a working code, please refer the OP.

Comment: Yes, thanks - I understand that. The question says as much, and in language equally as clear. It appears to be *you* that has misunderstood *my* comment. Perhaps the comment would have a better chance of being understood in the spirit it was intended if I emphasise it thusly. (laughs)Nobody ever wants to buy them, but *I* find great utility in at least knowing *how* to create a wheel. That's why I keep making them - for the sake of my own knowledge. - Oh, and as an addendum and in response to your first comment, "you're welcome". ;)

Answer (score 3):

The Window.getComputedStyle() method returns a [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#the-cssstyledeclaration-interface) collection.

This is an object which includes declarations and [indexed properties](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-supported-property-indices), if you want to create an object of declarations you just need to filter out the indexed properties,

try this:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#elem-container')
                                
var o = window.getComputedStyle(el)
var res = Object.keys(o).reduce((ac,x) => {
  if(isNaN(x))
    ac[x] = o[x];    
  return ac;
},{})



console.log(res)

console.log(camelToHyphen(res)) // also prefix moz and webkit


function camelToHyphen(s){
 return Object.keys(s).reduce((ac, x) => {
   var k = x.replace(/[A-Z]|^webkit|^moz/g, (c => '-' + c.toLowerCase() )) // converts  uppercase to - and lowercase
  
   return Object.assign(ac, {[k] : s[x]})
 },{})
}
```

```css
#elem-container{
   position: absolute;
   left:     100px;
   top:      200px;
   height:   100px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="elem-container">dummy</div>
```

Comment: Neat. However, I've just noticed that the webkit property names have missing characters. They all have a missing `-` i.e `webkitFilter` should be `-webkitFilter`

Comment: @enhzflep you can't have everything ;)    you can convert it to hyphen case but it may be more convenient to keep it this way.. anyway  i'll edit the question and add a function for transforming the keys

Comment: Thanks! I would not bother to convert the camelCase to kebab-case. I wasn't sure if such API existed, did not want to reinvent the wheel. Thanks for not only confirming but also providing the working solution.